# NSOpenPanel reopening after selection

Tags: objective-c, macos, appstore-sandbox

Some users are reporting that they cannot select files in my sandboxed app because when they select and item it reopens.

Nowhere in my code am I reopening the panel so I'm a bit confused as to why this would be happening.

One of my users said that the following message was logged in console a number of times:

`"Keychain sandbox consume extension error: s=-1 p= cannot allocate memory"`

I've asked them to run first aid on their keychain, and repair their disk permissions but that hasn't helped.

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this?

Thank you!

Here is the code that triggers the NSOpenPanel:

```
- (IBAction)selectHomeDirectory:(id)sender {
  NSOpenPanel *openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
  [openPanel setTitle:@"Select your home folder"];
  [openPanel setMessage:@"Select your home folder..."];
  [openPanel setPrompt:@"Choose"];
  [openPanel setCanCreateDirectories:NO];
  [openPanel setCanChooseFiles:NO];
  [openPanel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
  [openPanel setExtensionHidden:YES];
  [openPanel setAllowedFileTypes:nil];
  [openPanel setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
  [openPanel setDelegate:self];
  [openPanel setDirectoryURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/"]];

  [openPanel beginSheetModalForWindow:self.window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
    if(result != NSOKButton || !openPanel.URL){
      return;
    }

    /* Saves the scoped URL, and then triggers a view change */
  }];
}
```

Comment: >No where in my code  And where is your code?  What is your development target?  What is your Xcode version you are using?  Skipping basics won't get you anywhere.

Comment: Hey sorry I totally blanked on adding that info. I've added my the code that triggers the open panel to the question. I'm targeting 10.7 and 10.8, the issue is appearing on 10.8. I'm running Xcode 4.6.3.

Comment: Off topic, but: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select your home folder..."]` can be reduced down to `@Select your home folder..."`.

Comment: Thanks, I originally had it like that but I was making some changes and that never got reverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a Mavericks issue that was fixed in the later seeds.